# Jquery Expand Height with text overflow

Tags: jquery, css, height, expand

I'm trying to have a div's height expand automatically when its contained text overflows. Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/4nfNE/) on JSfiddle. This isn't the exact environment I need this function for but it is the same concept. I just need the jQuery to work properly and switch the classes. Help appreciated.

```
<div class="box">hello</div>
<br>
<div class="box">text is too long</div>

.box {
height: 30px;
width: 50px;
background: #666;
}
.boxfix {
height: 60px;
width: 50px;
background: #666;
}

var heightCheck = $(".box").height();

if (heightCheck > 30) {
$('.box').removeClass('box').AddClass('boxfix');
}
```

Update: I guess I wasn't super specific, I have attached two images that show my issue. I do not need to just extend the height, but also the "line-height" css property as well. That's why I figured changing the class in JQ would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the fiddle you linked in the comments (jsfiddle.net/4nfNE/6),
you set a height and a min-height in the same block...

```
color: #696969;
height: 23px;
line-height: 17px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding-left: 6px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
letter-spacing:1px;
min-height: 36px;
```

Changing 'height' to 'min-height' and removing the existing 'min-height' works for the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your heightfix jQuery and css code (it isn't really necessary in this situation) and change `height:30px;` to `min-height:30px;`.

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sqGkg/

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you simply need the `min-height` property but `min-height` alone will not be enough. To be compatible across all browsers simply use this.

```
<div class="box">hello</div>
<br/>
<div class="box">text is too long</div>

.box {
  min-height: 30px;
  height:auto!important; /* for modern browsers */
  height:30px; /* for old IE */
  width: 50px;
  background: #666;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nPmJC/1/)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNojq.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/duLoN.png
Here are pictures of my issue, the second is with min-height and a smaller line height, which looks good for the two lined LI items, but the formatting doesn't work for the one liners. Thats why I wanted to set them conditionally

Comment: Have tested with min-height only in IE 7/8/9, and several versions of Chrome and Firefox, and it works in all of them. Which browsers require the height: auto !important hack?

Comment: @NoahDamiani, can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the exact problem that you are having, as per those screenshots?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4nfNE/6/

I tried to make it as similar to the drupal site as possible.

Comment: @JoshLowry You are right. It's an old workaround for IE6... but if someone is still using IE6 then min-height is the least of their problems. :)

Comment: @NoahDamiani Not sure what you are looking for... is this it? http://jsfiddle.net/4nfNE/9/